What does this symbol “U” represents?
I know this is an 'union', but I would like to understand why it represent 'and' and doesn't represent 'or' instead.

I initially selected option D as my answer, but it was wrong..

I would have selected option D too. It looks llike a mistake in the test.

"$D$" is clearly the corret option. Who made this test ?

The use of a capital letter U rather than the \cup symbol is a bit lazy too... the test is wrong, you are correct.

I am surprised that there is a test asks for a meaning of a symbol, mathematics about the idea of theorems, proof and a lot of stuff but not about symbols.

See Union of two sets.

The symbol $\cup$ represents a "union" of sets. $A\cup B$ is the union of the sets $A$ and $B$,  which consists of "all of the elements of $A$ and $B$ together", i.e. "all the elements that are members of $A$ or $B$ (or both)".
This is not a good question both because 1.  and and or can both be used to describe the union, and 2. it seems to suggest that one of "and" and "or" goes with union and the other with intersection, but there's no way for "or" to go with intersection, so that choice D is preferable.

The symbol $\cup$ has a logical meaning or and this is how it is read by mathematicians.
In natural language, the words and and or are used with less care. Given the poor grammar in the question though (should be represent, not represents), I wouldn't worry too much about the official correct answer.

Are you talking about $\lor$?
